# Удаление от начала / от конца строки Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi

В текстовом файле расположено много строк, все строки разной длины. Нужен алгоритм как сделать:

1. В edit1 указываю число: Сколько Удалить символов - с начала строки.
2. В edit2 указываю число: Сколько Удалить символов - с конца строки.
3. Нажимаю кнопку и программа Обрезает все строки, в файле (1.txt), с начала и с конца. И сохраняет результат в файл 2.txt.

Пробовала переделать функцию с пробелами но опыта не достаточно. Может кто подскажет ?.

```
function Split(Str: String): String;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 1;
  while Str[1] in [' ',',','.',#13] do //удаление пробелов в начале
    Delete(Str, 1, 1);
  while I <= Length(Str) do
  begin
    if Str[I] in [' ',',','.',#13] then
    begin
      while ((Str[I+1] in [' ',',','.',#13]) or (Length(Str) = I)) and 
      (Length(Str) >= I) do
        //удаление пробелы между словами и в конце
        Delete(Str, I, 1);
      Inc(I);
    end;
  end;
  Result := Str;
end;
```

Comment: Также есть полезная функция для обрезания пробелов [Trim](http://www.delphibasics.ru/Trim.php)

Answer (score 3):

Вот так будет попроще:

```
function MyTrim(aString: string; aFromFront, aFromBack: Integer): string;
begin
  if aFromFront + aFromBack >= Length(aString) then
    // Если от строки ничего не останется, то возвращаем "пусто"
    Result := ''
  else
    // Копируем часть строки 
    Result := Copy(
                aString, 
                1+aFromFront, // с aFromFront символа (строка считается с 1-цы)
                Length(aString)-aFromFront-aFromBack); // Сколько символов копируем
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Все задачу решила. Если кому еще пригодиться то вот алгоритм.

```
n := strtoint(Edit1.Text); //удаляем в начале
k := strtoint(Edit2.Text); //удаляем в конце

if k>=length(s) then s:=''
else delete(s,length(s)-k+1,k);

if n>=length(s) then s:=''
else delete(s,1,n);

if s=''then // вывод сообщения
else //вывод полученной строки
```